# Google Sheets equation that doesn't go below zero

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an equation that looks like this in Google Sheets:

```
= (x - 500) ^ 0.38
```

The problem is that any value of x under 500 results in a cell value of `#NUM!` since zero to the power of 0.38 is not a real number.

How can I modify this equation so that instead of showing `#NUM!` it just shows 0 when x < 500?

Note: this is part of a larger formula:

```
= (x - 500) ^ 0.38 + ((-0.15 * y) + 36) + (52 - 7 * 1.01 * z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`IFERROR`** should do the trick for you:

```
=IFERROR((x - 500) ^ 0.38, 0)
```

or just **`IF`** it like:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER((x - 500) ^ 0.38), (x - 500) ^ 0.38, 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you, both variations of your answer worked perfectly!